# I want to Post the data from a Kendo Grid to controller

Tags: post, kendo-ui, grid

This is my view....This form submission is not working, and I want to send Text Box data into Controller when I click `".Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "SemesterRegistation"))"`...Any solution please

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditingInline_Create", "SemesterRegistation", FormMethod.Post, new { id="formID"}))
    {        
        <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" />        
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<SIMS.Models.Semester.SemesterRegistationModel>)Model.lis_semester_registration)
    .Name("grid")

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.SemesterID).Visible(false);
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.AcadamiYear, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["acadamicyear"], "Value", "Text")
        .Title("Acadamic Year");
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.AcadamicSemester, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["acadamicsemester"], "Value", "Text")
        .Title("Acadamic Semester");

        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.IntakeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["IntakeID"], "IntakeID", "IntakeCode")
        .Title("Intake");
        columns.Bound(o => o.From).Title("From").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("Date");
        columns.Bound(o => o.To).Title("To").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("Date");
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.ProgrammeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Programme"], "Id", "DegreeName")
        .Title("Programme");
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SpecializationID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Specialzation"], "SpecializationID", "SpecializationNameID")
        .Title("Specialzation").EditorTemplateName("SpecialzationID");

        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(182);
    })

    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("DetailSemester").Window(w => w.Width(850)))
    .Selectable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
            //.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(@<text>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <a href="/SemesterRegistation/EditingInline_Read?grid-mode=insert" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add">
                <span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Add New Record
            </a>
        </div>
        </text>);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(50)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.SemesterID); })
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "SemesterRegistation"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "SemesterRegistation"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "SemesterRegistation"))
    )
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)




//My Controller is here..In here "subjectids"  always null...But I want to get text box value to "subjectids"....

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult EditingInline_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, SemesterRegistationModel model)
        {
            string subjectids = Request.Form["tags"];//model.hdnIds;//;

            if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repSem = new SemesterRegistationRepository();
                bool res = repSem.Create(model,subjectids);
            }
            return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```

Comment: I solved this problem using java script

        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "SemesterRegistation").Data("loadMethos"))

This return value of text box

            function loadMethos() {
                return {
                    tags: $('#tags').val()                     
                };
               
            }

Answer (score -2):

The OP wrote:

> I solved this problem using java script:
>
> ```
>  .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "SemesterRegistation").Data("loadMethos"))
> ```
>
> This return value of text box
>
> ```
> function loadMethos() { return { tags: $('#tags').val() }; }
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)).